# Programmatically Click a Button on Web GUI after passing from Login Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, automation, browser-automation

I would like to programmatically Power on a Server Using SuperMicro Web GUI.

Initially the login page form `http://server1` code is

```
<form name="form1" action="/cgi/login.cgi" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <label style="width:85px; text-align:left; margin-right: 2px;">
        <script>
            document.writeln(lang.LANG_LOGIN_USERNAME)
        </script>Username
    </label>
    <input name="name" size="20" maxlength="64" style="width:146px;" type="text" onkeydown="checkEnt(event)">
    <label style="width:85px; text-align:left; margin-right: 2px;">
        <script>
            document.writeln(lang.LANG_LOGIN_PASSWORD)
        </script>Password
    </label>
    <input name="pwd" size="20" maxlength="64" style="width:146px;" type="password" onkeydown="checkEnt(event)">
    <input id="login_word" class="btnStyle" name="Login" type="button" onclick="javascript: checkform(this)" value="login">
</form>
```

[image]

After Typing the userename:password as `ADMIN:PASSWORD` it goes to a control page `http://server1/cgi/url_redirect.cgi?url_name=mainmenu` where the server can be switched on by clicking a button whose code is given below

```
<input type="button" class="btnStyle" id="btn_poweron" align="left" value="Power On">
```

[image]

The Entire HTML Code of the Login Page is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no_cache">
    <meta name="ATEN International Co Ltd." content="(c) ATEN International Co Ltd. 2010">
    <title></title>
    <!--    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/basic.css" type="text/css">
    <script language="JavaScript">
        if (window != top)
            top.location.href = "/"; //location.href;
    </script>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../js/utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" ,="" src="../js/lang/English/lang_str.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        var lang_setting;
        lang_setting = ReadCookie("language");
        if (lang_setting == null) {
            CreateCookie("langSetFlag", "0");
            CreateCookie("language", "English");
            lang_setting = "English";
        }
        document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\", src = \"../js/lang/" + lang_setting + "/lang_str.js\"><\/script>");

        function checkform() {
            if (Trim(form1.name.value) == "") {
                alert(lang.LANG_LOGIN_INVALID_USERNAME);
                form1.name.focus();
                return;
            }
            if (Trim(form1.pwd.value) == "") {
                alert(lang.LANG_LOGIN_INVALID_PASSWORD);
                form1.pwd.focus();
                return;
            }
            document.form1.submit();
            return;
        }

        function checkEnt(e) {
            var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            if (key == 13) {

                checkform();
            }
        }

        function PageInit() {
            var msg = document.getElementById("login_word");
            msg.setAttribute("value", lang.LANG_LOGIN_LOGIN);
            return;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" ,="" src="../js/lang/English/lang_str.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="PageInit()">
    <table style="margin: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%" border="0" background="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 25%; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center">
                    <table style="margin: 0 auto;" border="0" width="412px">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="../images/logo.gif" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width: 100%">
                <td style="height: 75%; vertical-align: top; text-align: center">
                    <table class="login">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h3><script>document.writeln(lang.LANG_LOGIN_PROMPT);</script>Please Login
</h3>
                                    <form name="form1" action="/cgi/login.cgi" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                                        <label style="width:85px; text-align:left; margin-right: 2px;">
                                            <script>
                                                document.writeln(lang.LANG_LOGIN_USERNAME)
                                            </script>Username
                                        </label>
                                        <input name="name" size="20" maxlength="64" style="width:146px;" type="text" onkeydown="checkEnt(event)">
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        <label style="width:85px; text-align:left; margin-right: 2px;">
                                            <script>
                                                document.writeln(lang.LANG_LOGIN_PASSWORD)
                                            </script>Password
                                        </label>
                                        <input name="pwd" size="20" maxlength="64" style="width:146px;" type="password" onkeydown="checkEnt(event)">
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        <input id="login_word" class="btnStyle" name="Login" type="button" onclick="javascript: checkform(this)" value="login">
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</body>

</html>
```

And the Entrie HTML Code of the PowerOn Page is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no_cache">
    <meta name="ATEN International Co Ltd." content="(c) ATEN International Co Ltd. 2010">
    <title></title>
    <!--    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico"> -->
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../js/utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" ,="" src="../js/lang/English/lang_str.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var lang_setting;
        /*
            EraseCookie("langSetFlag");
            EraseCookie("language");
        */
        EraseCookie("mainpage");
        EraseCookie("subpage");
        EraseCookie("RELOAD");
        lang_setting = ReadCookie("language");
        if (lang_setting == null) {
            CreateCookie("langSetFlag", "0");
            CreateCookie("language", "English");
            lang_setting = "English";
        }
        document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\", src = \"../js/lang/" + lang_setting + "/lang_str.js\"><\/script>");
        onunload = function() {
                var url = '/cgi/logout.cgi';
                var pars = '?time_stamp=' + (new Date());
                var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
                    url, {
                        method: 'post',
                        parameters: pars
                    } //reigister callback function
                );
            }
            -->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" ,="" src="../js/lang/English/lang_str.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<frameset cols="100%,*" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="../cgi/url_redirect.cgi?url_name=topmenu" id="TOPMENU" name="topmenu" scrolling="yes" noresize="false" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
</frameset>

</html>
```

Comment: So also when user refreshes the Control Page it should click button?

Comment: No...when i run the program it should execute it only once